# I want to get the condition for each tag and have table like this in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

how can get the data from different tag of xml in sql
output

```
tag                       condition
_________________         ____________
GroupHeaderBand1          nature  
GroupHeaderBand2          job
GroupHeaderBand3          name
```

input:

```
<StiSerializer version="1.02" type="Net" application="StiReport">
 <Pages isList="true" count="1">
  <Page1 Ref="3" type="Page" isKey="true">
   <Components isList="true" count="12">
     <GroupHeaderBand1 Ref="18" type="GroupHeaderBand" isKey="true">
      <Condition>Nature</Condition>
     </GroupHeaderBand1>
     <GroupHeaderBand2 Ref="21" type="GroupHeaderBand" isKey="true">
      <Condition>Job</Condition>
     </GroupHeaderBand2>
     <GroupHeaderBand3 Ref="26" type="GroupHeaderBand" isKey="true">
      <Condition>Name</Condition>
     </GroupHeaderBand3>
   </Components>
</Page1>
```

this is my xml code

Comment: Please enter your desired output.

Comment: And as per the question guide please show us what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

use following query

```
SELECT
   A.evnt.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') AS tag,
   A.evnt.value('(.)[1]','varchar(100)') as condition
FROM @XML.nodes('StiSerializer/Pages/Page1/Components/*') A(evnt)
```

or use

```
SELECT
       A.evnt.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') AS tag,
       A.evnt.value('(Condition/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as condition
FROM @XML.nodes('StiSerializer/Pages/Page1/Components/*') A(evnt)
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0ac8906391737fa9e33484ab8f66d765)

Comment: (.)[1] equals with Condition[1]. It does not matter which one you use.

Comment: If you use (.) You do not need to name the node.

Comment: Side note: `text()[1]` will be perform faster than `(.)[1]`. And possibly the `*` might need a predicate `*[type = "GroupHeaderBand"]` but only OP can answer that

Comment: I also put text()[1] in the answer.